# ionic capacitor open external app using intent url scheme

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I want to open an external app just player from my capacitor android app using the intent url structure `intent://<file url>#Intent;package=com.brouken.player;type=video;scheme=https;end` but it is not not working I have tried all the target options

vlc custom link `vlc://<file url>` just works and plays the supplied video url so I expected the intent format to also just work but that is not the case

```html
<a
    href="intent://filesamples.com/samples/video/mkv/sample_1920x1080.mkv#Intent;package=com.brouken.player;type=video;scheme=https;end"
>
    just player intent link
</a>
<br />
<br />
<a href="vlc://https://filesamples.com/samples/video/mkv/sample_1920x1080.mkv"> vlc intent link </a>
```

both the links work as expected in browser but in capacitor android the external app is not being launched for `intent://` url

Comment: I have already searched and gave a description of all the things I have tried maybe if you could link to something it would be useful